# What's the difference between convolution in Keras vs Caffe?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, caffe, convolution

I'm trying to replicate a large Caffe network into Keras (based on tensorflow backend). But I'm having a large trouble doing it even at a single convolutional layer.

**Simple Convolution in General**:

Let's say we had a 4D input with shape `(1, 500, 500, 3)`, and we had to perform a single convolution on this input with `96` filters with kernel size of `11` and `4x4` strides.

Let's set our weight and input variables:

```
w = np.random.rand(11, 11, 3, 96)  # weights 1
b = np.random.rand(96)  # weights 2 (bias)

x = np.random.rand(500, 500, 3)
```

**Simple Convolution in Keras**:

This is how it could be defined in Keras:

```
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import Conv2D
import numpy as np

inp = Input(shape=(500, 500, 3))
conv1 = Conv2D(filters=96, kernel_size=11, strides=(4, 4), activation=keras.activations.relu, padding='valid')(inp)                                                            


model = keras.Model(inputs=[inp], outputs=conv1)
model.layers[1].set_weights([w, b])  # set weights for convolutional layer


predicted = model.predict([x.reshape(1, 500, 500, 3)])
print(predicted.reshape(1, 96, 123, 123))  # reshape keras output in the form of Caffe
```

**Simple Convolution in Caffe**:

`simple.prototxt`:

```
name: "simple"
input: "inp"
input_shape {
  dim: 1
  dim: 3
  dim: 500
  dim: 500
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "inp"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 96
    kernel_size: 11
    pad: 0
    stride: 4
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
}
```

Caffe in Python:

```
import caffe

net = caffe.Net('simple.prototxt', caffe.TEST)
net.params['conv1'][0].data[...] = w.reshape(96, 3, 11, 11)  # set weights 1
net.params['conv1'][1].data[...] = b  # set weights 2 (bias)
net.blobs['inp'].reshape(1, 3, 500, 500) # reshape input layer to fit our input array x
print(net.forward(inp=x.reshape(1, 3, 500, 500)).get('conv1'))
```

**Problem**:

If we executed both of the snippets of code, we would notice that outputs are different from each other. I understand that there are few differences such as symmetric padding of Caffe, but I didn't even use padding here. Yet the output of Caffe is different from output of Keras...

Why is this so? I know that Theano backend doesn't utilize correlation like Caffe does and hence it requires kernel to be rotated by 180 degrees, but is it the same for tensorflow? from what I know, both Tensorflow and Caffe use cross-correlation instead of Convolution.

How could I make two identical models in Keras and Caffe that use convolution?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, but I'm not sure how to fix it yet...

The difference between these two convolutional layers is alignment of their items. This **alignment** problem only occurs when number of filters are equal to `N` such that `N > 1 && N > S` where `S` is dimension of filter. In other words, such problem only occurs when we get a multi-dimensional array from convolution which has **both number of rows and number of columns greater than 1**.

## Evidence:

To see this, I simplified my input and output data so that we can better analyze the mechanics of both layers.

`simple.prototxt`:

```
input: "input"
input_shape {
  dim: 1
  dim: 1
  dim: 2
  dim: 2
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "input"
  top: "conv1"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 2
    kernel_size: 1
    pad: 0
    stride: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
}
```

`simple.py`:

```
import keras
import caffe
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D
from keras.activations import relu
from keras import Model

filters = 2  # greater than 1 and ker_size
ker_size = 1 

_input = np.arange(2 * 2).reshape(2, 2)
_weights = [np.reshape([[2 for _ in range(filters)] for _ in range(ker_size*ker_size)], (ker_size, ker_size, 1, filters)), np.reshape([0 for _ in range(filters)], (filters,))]  # weights for Keras, main weight is array of 2`s while bias weight is array of 0's
_weights_caffe = [_weights[0].T, _weights[1].T]  # just transpose them for Caffe

# Keras Setup

keras_input = Input(shape=(2, 2, 1), dtype='float32')
keras_conv = Conv2D(filters=filters, kernel_size=ker_size, strides=(1, 1), activation=relu, padding='valid')(keras_input)
model = Model(inputs=[keras_input], outputs=keras_conv)
model.layers[1].set_weights([_weights[0], _weights[1]])

# Caffe Setup

net = caffe.Net("simpler.prototxt", caffe.TEST)
net.params['conv1'][0].data[...] = _weights_caffe[0]
net.params['conv1'][1].data[...] = _weights_caffe[1]
net.blobs['input'].data[...] = _input.reshape(1, 1, 2, 2)


# Predictions


print("Input:\n---")
print(_input)
print(_input.shape)
print("\n")

print("Caffe:\n---")
print(net.forward()['conv1'])
print(net.forward()['conv1'].shape)
print("\n")

print("Keras:\n---")
print(model.predict([_input.reshape(1, 2, 2, 1)]))
print(model.predict([_input.reshape(1, 2, 2, 1)]).shape)
print("\n")
```

**Output**:

```
Input:
---
[[0 1]
 [2 3]]
(2, 2)


Caffe:
---
[[[[0. 2.]
   [4. 6.]]

  [[0. 2.]
   [4. 6.]]]]
(1, 2, 2, 2)


Keras:
---
[[[[0. 0.]
   [2. 2.]]

  [[4. 4.]
   [6. 6.]]]]
(1, 2, 2, 2)
```

**Analysis**:

If you look at output by the Caffe model, you'll notice that our `2x2` array is first doubled (so that we have an array of 2 `2x2` arrays) and then matrix multiplication is performed on each of those two arrays with our weight matrix. Something like this:

**Original**:

```
[[[[0. 2.]
   [4. 6.]]

  [[0. 2.]
   [4. 6.]]]]
```

**Transformed**:

```
[[[[(0 * 2) (2 * 2)]
   [(4 * 2) (6 * 2)]]

  [[(0 * 2) (2 * 2)]
   [(4 * 2) (6 * 2)]]]]
```

Tensorflow does something different, it seems to first **align 2D vectors of output in ascending order** after doing the same thing as Caffe did. This seems like a weird behavior, and I'm unable to understand why would they do such thing.

## Solution:

I have answered my own question about **the cause** of the problem, but I'm not aware of any clean solution yet. I still don't find my answer satisfying enough hence I'm going to accept the question which has the actual solution.

The only solution I know is creation of custom layer, which is not a very neat solution to me.