# How to stop Keras from ordering layer output?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create a `Conv2D` layer in Keras (with tensorflow backend) and I've noticed that its output is ordeed in ascending manner.

For example, consider a simple input such as this:

```
_input = np.arange(2 * 2).reshape(2, 2)
```

which results in:

```
[[0 1]
 [2 3]]
```

---

If we pass the `_input` variable to a convolutional layer like this:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D
from keras.activations import relu
from keras import Model
import numpy as np

filters = 2
filter_size = 1

_weights = [np.reshape([[2 for _ in range(filters)] for _ in range(filter_size*filter_size)], (filter_size, filter_size, 1, filters)), np.reshape([0 for _ in range(filters)], (filters,))]  # weights for Keras, main weight is array of 2`s while bias weight is array of 0's

keras_input = Input(shape=(2, 2, 1), dtype='float32')

keras_conv = Conv2D(filters=filters, kernel_size=filter_size, strides=(1, 1), activation=relu, padding='valid')(keras_input)

model = Model(inputs=[keras_input], outputs=keras_conv)
model.layers[1].set_weights([_weights[0], _weights[1]])

print(model.predict([_input.reshape(1, 2, 2, 1)]))
```

We would get an ordered output:

```
[[[[0. 0.]
   [2. 2.]]

  [[4. 4.]
   [6. 6.]]]]
```

It seems like, tensorflow does something like this:

1. perform matrix multiplication on input with each filter
2. add bias to the matrix from the first step
3. perform ascending ordering on the output of the second step

I want to eliminate the **3rd** step, so that I get something like this:

```
[[[[0. 2.]
   [4. 6.]]

  [[0. 2.]
   [4. 6.]]]]
```

For example, Caffe would skip the ordering part and its output would be exactly the same as the output above.

This is how Caffe would perform "convolution":

```
[[[[(0*2) + 0 (1*2) + 0]
   [(2*2) + 0 (3*2) + 0]]

  [[(0*2) + 0 (1*2) + 0]
   [(2*2) + 0 (3*2) + 0]]]]
```

which equals to:

```
[[[[0. 2.]
   [4. 6.]]

  [[0. 2.]
   [4. 6.]]]]
```

This is done, without altering the order of our input, as you can see.

## Briefly

How do I stop Tensorflow (or Keras) from ordering the activation of convolutional layers? Is there any parameter that I can pass to eliminate this ascending order?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I run your code and it produces input shape errors. Also Keras does not do any kind of ordering of the output, its not a general step. You might be misled by your inputs.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Hello, I apologize for the broken code, I fixed it now - it should return the exact same output as seen in the question above. As you see the output is ordered because its last elements are the greatest and its first elements are the least.

Comment: The input is also ordered, that's why you get an ordered output. As I said, Keras doesn't order the output (why would it do that?).

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro [I'm trying to mimic the ordering performed in Caffe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54736184/6083655), in this specific case, Caffe would make a multidimensional array containing `2x2` `_input` matrices, and then it would multiply each of the item of that matrix by `2` (since our filter is full of `2`s). Matrix created by Keras would contain the same elements, but it would align the elements of matrix in ascending order. Did you assert that it's the `Input` layer that does this ordering? Thank you!

Comment: You have a conceptual misunderstanding, Keras does not do any ascending ordering, that is just by chance. You will have to dig a lot deeper to find what Keras and Caffe do differently.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro You are corrrect, it's all about the input order. Caffe takes input in channels first scheme so it performs convolution horizontally on roes of the matrix, whereas Keras passes the input in the channels last scheme and hence convolution is performed on each column vertically. I wasn't able to see this until you mentioned the input ordering, thank you very much!